# Searching Content Back-end

Tags: control-panel

Currently in the admin panel, all entries per channel appear in a single list. Is it at all possible (at least, by default) to filter/search by type?

For instance a dropdown of all entry types, or just 'type: article' in the search form.

I know it is quite easy to do from the front-end, would it require a plugin to add the functionality to the back-end?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching

Anywhere there is a search bar in the control panel, you can use any of the syntaxes listed on that page.

Comment: I saw that page but I can't see anything on it to do with the entry types? I don't want to search within the posts, just to list the posts of a particular type.

Comment: Ahh, sorry missed that part. About 99% sure that's not possible at the moment.

Comment: Just to jump in here as well. If you are searching in "All Entries", then I don't think that it is searching for the Author name. So, if the Author was "Tom Bowler" searching that exact phrase won't bring up any entries by that user. If not, it really would be a nice to have to avid any confusion client end.